# Getting a THICK h1

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, heading

I've been doing website design for a long time now but one thing which has me absolutely stumped is how people achieve that THICK bold h1 effect.
Here is a nice example of what I mean -

[image]

Even after applying the font weight of 700 it always seems to look thin (regardless of whatever font I pick) -

[image]

I'm probably going to feel so stupid when I find out how its done.

Comment: it's based on font family and font weight

Comment: Are you using the same font as that example?

Comment: Did you tried font-weight : bold?

Comment: @UdhayTitus Could you please elaborate on this.

Comment: @Swellar No in this case BUT I have tried it before with the same fonts as the example and I can never get it as bold.

Comment: @User Yeah its no different to font-weight : 700

Answer (score 2):

You need to try a different font. The one in the example picture looks similar to [Bebas Neue](http://www.dafont.com/bebas-neue.font).

However, you can also very easily see exactly what CSS was used to achieve that effect by right-clicking the text and selecting `Inspect Element` in Chrome.

---

By googling that exact text I found the [website you were looking at](https://drivetribe.com/), and from that we can see they they're using a custom font, `DriveTribe`:

[image: example]

Comment: This was just a fast example, I've come across websites doing it in the past with different fonts. I'll give your suggested font a test though.

Comment: @user3599852 How'd you go? Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the text bold with the `<b></b>` or `<strong></strong>` tags?

```css
p {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 font-size: 60px;
 font-family: Verdana
}
```

```html
<p><strong>This is a text</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see whether your font has a heavier style available. For example, I was using the default style (i.e., 'regular') of this one not realizing that there are other styles available: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat